# How can I change the block theme

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image]

Can I use vscode api to change the theme between line 37 and 50 ?

Comment: That looks like a selection you have made.  If so, try this `colorCustomization`:  `editor.selectionBackground`.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 0):

Themes are not based on line numbers but on tokens. Tokens are defined by regular expressions which are applied to the entire file, not just a part of it.

So, no you cannot change the theme between 2 lines.